# create custom intro screen slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i need to create something like this 
[image: intro slider like this]

i am using intro slider plugin from flutter but it does not support 2 images
i have tried

```
 slides.add(
      new Slide(
        pathImage: 'assets/logo_1.png',
        description:
            "Find trusted help for everything on your to-do-list.",
        styleDescription: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 18.0,
        ),
        marginDescription: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
        backgroundImage: "assets/ss4.jpg",
        backgroundOpacity: 0.0,
      ),
    );

 IntroSlider(
              slides: this.slides,
              colorActiveDot: Color(0xFF17b01b),
              sizeDot: 10.0,
              isShowSkipBtn: false,
              styleNameDoneBtn: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF17b01b),
                fontSize: 15.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
              nameDoneBtn: 'Got it >',
              nameNextBtn: 'Got it >',
                  onDonePress:this.onDonePress ,
            )),
```

Intro slider support two images but 2nd one is for background image so my image takes full background of screen in intro slider , how can i set 2nd image in center like in image i have attached?
or how can i give height width to background image in intro slider ??

Comment: Can you add both images for the slider.

Comment: note that the `backgroundOpacity` is set to 0 so it won't show the background image.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the plugin docs https://pub.dev/packages/intro_slider you can set a image height and width like this:

```
new Slide(
        pathImage: 'assets/logo_1.png',
        // Added the next 3 lines
        heightImage: 500,
        widthImage: 300,
        foregroundImageFit: BoxFit.contain,
        description:
            "Find trusted help for everything on your to-do-list.",
        styleDescription: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 18.0,
        ),
        marginDescription: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
        backgroundImage: "assets/ss4.jpg",
        backgroundOpacity: 0.0,
      ),
```

**Edit**

Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

You can put any custon widget in the `centerWidget` property like this:

```
new Slide(
        centerWidget: Column(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
                Text("image1 placeholder"),
                Text("some text"),
                Text("image2 placeholder"),
            ],
        ),
        backgroundImage: "assets/ss4.jpg",
        backgroundOpacity: 0.0,
      ),
```

Comment: this cant be set image as i want in uploaded image @Zvi Karp

Comment: @urvashi sorry, I misunderstood the question, have updated the answer.